# vb .net How can I remove a filename from the collection returned by GetFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles returns "Returns a read-only collection of strings representing the names of files within a directory."

I want to randomly select a file in the collection, process it, delete it from the list, and repeat until all files processed.

I can think of only copying the collection from GetFiles to a mutable collection.
But GetFiles may eventually be returning millions of file names.

Answer (score 4):

Just put a `.ToList()` at the end of the function call.

Rather than randomly selecting your item from the middle of the list, I also suggest shuffling the list and iterating the shuffled items. That will be easier than deleting items from a collection.

Comment: Sweet!  Great idea.  What shuffle method do you recommend for this case?

Comment: Wow, am not sure if shuffling, which is complex, is more efficient than simply deleting each file from list, which may be very fast if linked list.

Comment: but `List<T>` is **not** a linked list. Every time you delete an item from a list (call `List.Remove()` or `List.RemoveAt()`, .Net allocates a new buffer of the correct size and copies all of the elements to the new buffer. For shuffling, yes, you'll need to write your own shuffle -- the framework should really have included this out of the box:( -- but just google for Fisher-Yates and you'll find plenty of example code showing how to do it without too much fuss.

Answer (score 1):

Using this generic function to shuffle based on [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm)

```vb
Shared r = New Random() ' must not create new Random each time

Public Shared Function Shuffle(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim n = source.Count()
    Dim a(n - 1) As T
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Dim j = r.Next(0, i + 1)
        If i <> j Then
            a(i) = a(j)
        End If
        a(j) = source(i)
    Next
    Return a
End Function
```

you can then iterate over the shuffled list. No need to remove items if iterating.

```vb
Dim source = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:/")
Dim result = Shuffle(source)
For Each r In result
    ' process file
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

my_mutable_list = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( my_dir_path).ToList()

Then, just delete each file as needed from my_mutable_list.